# yum update could not retrieve mirrorlist

Tags: proxy, centos7, yum

Im trying to install a web service with centos 7 apache and sql server. For that purpose, Im using VMware, the installation of OS finish successfully but when I try to update centos it gives me this error:

```
#yum update
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was 14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
```

The thing is, this is a remote machine (from the company Im working with) and Im almost sure they are using somekind of firewall/proxy. When I do:

```
#curl -v mirrorlist.centos.org
>get /?release=7 http/1.1
>user-agent: curl/7.29.0
>host: mirrorlist.centos.org
>accept:*/*
*http 1.0, assume close after body
<http/1.0 403 forbidden
<content-lenght: 479
<content-type: text/html
<server: mikrotik httpproxy
<proxy-connection: close
```

Is the network under a proxy? If it is how can I prove this in order to show my boss and start setting up the web service. I cant install nothing either.
Thank you, regards.
EDIT: I forgot to mention that I can browse to `http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock` on chrome without problems and see all urls in the host (windows 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already proved that the server is behind a proxy, because the proxy that intercepted the request identifed itself as `mikrotik httpproxy`. What to do about it depends on what that Mikrotik device is, why you're proxying to it at all, and what it's meant to be doing.

Comment: Hello Michael! Not sure, like I said before, Im not in charge of network management and this was a remote computer. So, the reason I dont reach mirrorlist is for that server right? But I could enter via web browser to `http://mirrorlist.centos.org`, thats what I got confused... The list of links on mirrorlist are blocked by the proxy so thats why yum fails? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Yes, your request was intercepted by that device and refused. You will need to ask whoever is responsible for the Mikrotik device to reconfigure it.

Comment: I saw the network configuration on Windows 10 (host) but there I dont see any proxy configured and I downloaded centos iso from that host... Im confused... but well, at least I know the fault is not coming from centos. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to use proxy to make secure and audit able environment, you can still work with  yum behind the proxy add below lines to youe yum file /etc/yum.conf
proxy=http://:
proxy_username=user
proxy_password=password

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hello asktyagi! Something weird happend, I installed vmware pro 14 in my desktop, the remote machine is using vmware 12. Like i said, the yum didnt work at all on remote computer, so i did a installation on vmware 14 plus a backup and uploaded to google drive. Downloaded to remote machine and opened via vmware and now it runs yum without problems... or maybe my boss is just trying to troll me, not sure. Thx for the help!